# requirejs support for remotely loaded dojo with ArcGIS/ESRI

Tags: dojo, requirejs, webstorm

I'm working on a project with [ArcGIS/ESRI](https://developers.arcgis.com) in WebStorm. According to the [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/inside_dojoversion.html), "Dojo is included with the ArcGIS JavaScript API so there is no need to host/reference/install it."  This means WebStorm has no idea what `require` is:

[image]

How do I add support without installing Dojo/require?

Answer (score 0):

Was just going to comment, but can't yet?! Anyway, I had to reengineer my web-site dev-ops to account for the ESRI javascript API. I am using 4.6 though...

The API, which includes dojo, may be installed, but it has to be configured into  your site. Once you reference dojo/dojo.js, all will be good. But you need the config set-up first.

Start here:
https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/11/13/using-bower-for-custom-builds-of-arcgis-api-for-javascript/

https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/11/13/using-bower-for-custom-builds-of-arcgis-api-for-javascript/

There is a link to the API javascript resources. This will really help understand the process!
https://github.com/Esri/jsapi-resources

Also don't miss:

https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules_advanced/

https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/dojo_config/

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/build/

I am just getting this stuff "almost" working. And actually had a build question to post and saw this. Hope it helps. I was using AMD and thought I had to go the requirejs route, but the dojo stuff worked out better for me. Check them both out and see what works for you! Good Luck!